# Switch async Task to sync task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(items.Select(p =>
{
    return CreateItem(p);
}).ToArray(), completedTasks => { Console.WriteLine("completed"); });
```

Is it possible to convert `ContinueWhenAll` to a synchronous method? I want to switch back between async and sync.

Edit: I should metnion that each of the "tasks" in the continuewhenall method should be executing synchronously.

Comment: Based on your edit, you *don't* want to just wait synchronously for the tasks to complete?  You want to force them to run on the same thread in order 1 by 1?

Comment: yes run them in order 1 by 1.

Comment: BTW, it's considered good practice to name async methods with an "Async" postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave your existing code intact and have a variable option of executing synchronously you should make these changes:

```
bool isAsync = false; // some flag to check for async operation

var batch = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(items.Select(p =>
{
    return CreateItem(p);
}).ToArray(), completedTasks => { Console.WriteLine("completed"); });

if (!isAsync)
    batch.Wait();
```

This way you can toggle it programmatically instead of by editing your source code.  And you can keep the continuation code the same for both methods.

Edit:

Here is a simple pattern for having the same method represented as a synchronous and async version:

```
public Item CreateItem(string name)
{
    return new Item(name);
}

public Task<Item> CreateItemAsync(string name)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateItem(name));
}
```

Comment: It results in the exception: RunSynchronously may not be called on a continuation task.

Comment: It won't work at this level.  You will notice that most classes which support async operations have two sister methods, such as `HttpClient.Get()` and `HttpClient.GetAsync()`, etc.  The problem is that it is assumed you are already starting your task asynchronously from within the `CreateItem` method itself.

Comment: Your best option is to offer two methods, `CreateItem` and `CreateItemAsync` if you really need them to be able to run in a specific order on the current thread.  `CreateItemAsync` would just wrap around the functionality of `CreateItem` by calling it in a Task.  You would have to post the code for how you implemented `CreateItem` if you need help doing that part.

Answer (score 1):

Unless am mistaken this is what you're looking for

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
//continuation code here
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try this.

using **TaskContinuationOptions** for a simple scenario.

```
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.Defau

var random = new Random();
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(p => {
    return taskFactory.StartNew(() => {
        var timeout = random.Next(5, p * 50);
        Thread.Sleep(timeout / 2);
        Console.WriteLine(@"  1: ID = " + p);
        return p;
    }).ContinueWith(t => {
        Console.WriteLine(@"* 2: ID = " + t.Result);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}).ToArray();

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

or using **TPL Dataflow** for a complex scenario.

```
var step2 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {
    Thread.Sleep(i);
    Console.WriteLine(@"* 2: ID = " + i);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
    //MaxMessagesPerTask = 1
});

var random = new Random();
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(p => {
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        var timeout = random.Next(5, p * 50);
        Thread.Sleep(timeout / 2);
        Console.WriteLine(@"  1: ID = " + p);
        return p;
    }).ContinueWith(t => {
        Thread.Sleep(t.Result);
        step2.Post(t.Result);
    });
}).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t => step2.Complete());
await step2.Completion;
```